# Upgrading spring security to version 4 from 3 - LogoutFilter

Tags: spring-security

I have a class MyLogoutProcessingFilter which extends from LogoutFilter.

In the old LogoutFilter there was a method called getFilterProcessesUrl.  I used to call it in this manner.

```
    @Override
    public String getFilterProcessesUrl() {
        return super.getFilterProcessesUrl();
    }
```

Since 4.0.0 this method was removed.  What should I replace it with?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what to do here?

Comment: I put the task aside for the moment and used the older version of the library.  It was related to trying to use the Spring SAML package with spring security 4.  I was trying to figure out what to replace the call back with.  I expect to come back to it soon.